# Get records from db within a limit range

Tags: mongodb

Assume that my database returns 1000 records based on a query that I have.

What I wish to do is using the same query, get the first 100 records, then get the next 100 and so on until I have all the 1000.

That is, I do not want all the 100 records in one go. I need them in batches of 100.

So something like this perhaps:

```
query = {
    '$from': 0,
    '$to': 100
}
```

with the first request followed by

```
query = {
    '$from': 100,
    '$to': 200
}
```

for the next request and so on.

I don't want all 1000 results at once. I wish to be able to specify the start and end counts so that I get the result in batches - is this possible in mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `skip` and `limit` for your queries.

For example..

```
db.myCollection.find().limit(100) //Get the first 100 records
db.myCollection.find().skip(100).limit(100) //Get the next 100 records
```

This is an expensive method though, I would much rather get all 1000 and "separate" them client-side.

Here's a link to both method's docs

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/